# Issue while uploading the large video files

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to upload a video of size 670 MB. While uploading I am getting error.

```
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

I am using the following code.

```
byte[] myData = new Byte[nFileLen];
myFile.InputStream.Read(myData, 0, nFileLen);
System.IO.FileStream newFile
= new System.IO.FileStream(Server.MapPath(sSavePath + sFilename),
System.IO.FileMode.Create);
newFile.Write(myData, 0, myData.Length);
newFile.Close();
```

EDIT

It is being uploaded at intranet network only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses. Actually the issue is with server not allowing large files to upload. When I creating virtual directory on my machine and uploading then allows me.

Answer (score 2):

From [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/uploadlargefilesaspnet.aspx):

> During the construction of an intranet application that allows users
>   to upload documents and share information between users, I noticed
>   that when a user tries to upload files that are larger than 4 MB, he
>   is asked for the user/password and even if he enters the correct
>   user/password, the file is not uploaded, and he gets a HTTP 401.1
>   error.
>
> Of course, this should not be an article, but CodeProject doesn't have
>   a "quick tip section"-like, so here it goes.
>
> By default, Machine.config is configured to accept HTTP Requests upto
>   4096 KB (4 MB) and it is reflected in all your ASP.NET applications.
>   You can change the Machine.config file directly, or you can change
>   only the Web.config file of the application(s) you want to.
>
> Open your Web.config file, and just below the `<system.web>` tag, add
>   the following tag:
>
> ```
> <httpRuntime 
> executionTimeout="90" 
> maxRequestLength="4096" 
> useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" 
> minFreeThreads="8" 
> minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" 
> appRequestQueueLimit="100" 
> enableVersionHeader="true"
> />
> ```
>
> Now, just take a look at the maxRequestLength="4096" attribute of the
>    tag. As you may have realized, all you need to do is
>   change the value to some other value of your choice (8192 for 8 Mb,
>   16384 for 16 Mb, 65536 for 64 Mb, and so on...).
>
> That's it. I hope it is useful to you.

[Large File Uploading in
 ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/mhawley/archive/2004/05/11/129824.aspx) 
[Large file uploads in
 ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Actually the issue is with server not allowing large files to upload. When I creating virtual directory on my machine and uploading then allows me.

Answer (score 0):

In order to upload files:
Default file size is 4096 KB approx 5 MB
We can increase size by updating maxRequestLength to max 11264 KB approx 11 MB

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Actually the issue is with server not allowing large files to upload. When I creating virtual directory on my machine and uploading then allows me.